# Running SSRS Reports on Azure

Tags: reporting-services, cloud

We have developed new reports for a client that has never run SSRS reports before. What I am trying to figure out if it's possible to avoid installing SSRS on the client side altogether. And if that's not possible, at least have him running reports using his local Report Server while reports are hosted on the cloud to avoid any local report publishing. Is something like this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can get an Azure machine or SQL SERVER (SSRS) installation on the Azure cloud to store and process reports (it's not required SSRS installation on the client side but AD configuration is required). However I'd like to know why your client can use a local Report Server installation but without reports on it.

Comment: Knowing how ridiculously complicated report deployment is I foreseen that a client might have a problem publishing reports on their end. I also have not found a tool or something to create scripts that would automate that process. That's why I am trying to see other options.

Comment: Even if you use the Azure approach your client will have problems to publish reports if he doesn't know troubleshooting in SSRS. It would be better you train one person in the client team for publishing reports.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use rldc/Local reports ([Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.aspx) or [Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.report.aspx)) rather than rdl/Report Server Reports you can host your reports inside of a .net application, possibly even building one only for reports. You do loose some of the enterprisy features like subscriptions and the export options are somewhat limited (excel, pdf and word only). The  Rdlc and rdl schemas are pretty close, you might be able to simply rename them and add them to a .net application or you might have to manually tweak the xml.